# How to prevent Linux kernel from evicting file-backed executable pages when about to run out of RAM? (which would otherwise cause disk-thrashing)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, out-of-memory

The purpose of this is to prevent the kernel from causing lots of disk reads(effectively freezing the system) when about to run out of RAM, even when there is no swap enabled, but before OOM-killer triggers!

Note: the value of `vm.swappiness` (sysctl) has no effect on this! Turning off swap(all swap partitions are off) also has no effect.

I'm guessing either the answer requires recompiling kernel with certain `.config` options(I asked about this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463233/building-custom-kernel-with-kswapd0-disabled)) which I haven't yet tried(because I don't know how to [recompile kernel for my OS](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/125446/how-to-compile-an-appvm-custom-kernel-in-qubes-os-fedora-28/)), but more than likely it may require patching the kernel (hence why this question is on SO, was I wrong to put it here?). But maybe there are other ways, I've no idea.

For further details of when code pages get evicted, see:
1. this answer and the comment beneath it: https://askubuntu.com/a/432827/861003
2. the answer and David Schwartz comments of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24646/306023

I'm pasting the comment from point 1 here:

> For example, consider a case where you have zero swap and system is
>   nearly running out of RAM. The kernel will take memory from e.g.
>   Firefox (it can do this because Firefox is running executable code
>   that has been loaded from disk - the code can be loaded from disk
>   again if needed). If Firefox then needs to access that RAM again N
>   seconds later, the CPU generates "hard fault" which forces Linux to
>   free some RAM (e.g. take some RAM from another process), load the
>   missing data from disk and then allow Firefox to continue as usual.
>   This is pretty similar to normal swapping and kswapd0 does it. – Mikko
>   Rantalainen Feb 15 at 13:08

I'm actually keeping track of these disk-thrashing situations(due to code-pages being evicted, then re-read, then evicted again, etc.) occurring on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/constantoverride/84eba764f487049ed642eb2111a20830) (there are screenshots too, eg. iotop)

**EDIT:** Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373312/306023
**EDIT2:** I also asked this(OP question) on the linux-kernel mailing list (here: https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/8/22/176) but there was no reply.
**EDIT3:** found a way, patching kernel with patch from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52067753/10239615) question.

Comment: Are you looking for [mlock / mlockall](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock)?

Comment: @Michael maybe, but I need the kernel to do this automatically/seamlessly for every executable/lib 's code pages.  EDIT: maybe a potential kernel patch would consist of such calls?

Comment: Ok, I found a way, see kernel patch inside [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52067753/10239615) question. But not sure how good it is, even though it does the job, since I made it and I'm noob ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward answer to this question in Linux kernel design.
Let me share my thoughts here.

There are two kinds of pages as per Linux memory management: ANON PAGES & FILE PAGES.
ANON PAGES: Anonymous pages hold data/buffers. These pages do not have any file backing or disk backing. eg: kmalloc/vmalloc/malloc buffers.
FILE PAGES: These pages hold the contents of files (DLL, text segment of binaries, shared libraries). Generally holds the data which is available on secondary storage.

Code pages (in other words, File pages) are marked as RECLAIMABLE pages as these pages can be regenerated at any point of time.
In memory crunch situation, kswapd tries to evict the RECLAIMABLE pages to free the RAM space. Later, kswapd tries to swap ANON pages to get more free space.
If the memory crunch situation is severe, OOM killer is triggered to kill a process to free the memory.

As per this design, Code pages are the first target in memory crunch situation. 
Playing around with swapping (either turning off swap or changing vm.swappiness) will not be helpful as File pages will never be swapped. Only anon pages are swapped since these pages can not be regenerated.

The main problem in this scenario is RAM space is very less. If the problem persists, you may need to upgrade the RAM size.

ANDROID has come up with an alternative to such kind of scenarios (as you mentioned the example of Firefox): Low Memory Killer (LMK).
Android middleware will categorize the apps into: 
    FOREGROUND APPS
    VISIBLE APPS
    SERVICE APPS
    CACHED APPS
    HIDDEN APPS
    BACKGROUND APPS
Above terminology might not be correct, but this is how they categorize and foreground apps of high priority and background apps of low priority.
Whenever there is a memory crunch situation, LMK will choose a low priority app/process/task and kill that.
In your example, 
    Firefox will not be killed as it is frequently used, thus it is categorized as CACHED APP.

To avoid disk thrashing, middleware has to come up with such a new design if it is convinced that you have enough RAM for your project.

Comment: Could you point to the kernel code that does this what you said: "Code pages (in other words, File pages) are marked as RECLAIMABLE pages as these pages can be regenerated at any point of time". Because I'd love to change it so they don't get marked.

Comment: You can grep for __GFP_RECLAIM flag allocations in the code. One such example is fs/cachefiles/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

The memory.min parameter in the cgroups-v2 memory controller should help.

Namely, let me quote:

> Hard memory protection. If the memory usage of a cgroup is within its
>   effective min boundary, the cgroup’s memory won’t be reclaimed under
>   any conditions. If there is no unprotected reclaimable memory
>   available, OOM killer is invoked.

Source : https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html

That is, create a single "sysdefault" cgroup with a memory controller.
Set the memory.min parameter equal to the size of your RAM.
Voila: your anonymous pages may be swapped our, but your file-based pages will never get reclaimed.

Comment: Would you please give all the steps that do what you say? I tried it but `cgroup.controllers` is empty thus I cannot `# echo '+memory' > cgroup.subtree_control`, for example.

Comment: ok I did it by making `systemd` use cgroups v2, setting 4GiB `memory.min` for each of the 3(all) cgroups: `user.slice`, `init.scope` and `system.slice`, but it seems to not have worked since `Active File:` reached under 10MiB during memory pressure: [more info](https://gist.github.com/constantoverride/84eba764f487049ed642eb2111a20830#gistcomment-2965869)